# css media JS does not work for media style

Tags: javascript, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.mobile {display:none;}
.desktop {display:block;}

@media screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .mobile {display:block;}
    .desktop {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="desktop">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p id=result></p>
</div>
<div class="mobile">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p id=result></p>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = 2;
        var y = x + 3;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = y;
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS works only for desktops with screen width more 320 px. When browser s window is resized under 320 px, function does not work. Why?

Comment: remember, `id` should be unique, dont duplicate `id`. `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = y;`, this is updating the `result`, but only one element is updated, since you are using `id`, it updates the first occurrence.  Replace `id` or you some other logic, you will get the result

Comment: I guess your confusion boils down to the fact that `display:none` has no influence on the DOM (js) accessibilty of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only outputting it with `getElementById()`. This function will only grab the first element of the DOM and update it. In the case of the smaller than 320 this element is hidden, so is your input.

I now have updated it so both `<p>` elements have a different id and updated them both in your `myFunction()` event handler. This way both are updated when you are emitting the click event.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = 2;
  var y = x + 3;
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```css
  .mobile {
  display: none;
}

.desktop {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
  <p id=result1></p>
</div>
<div class="mobile">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
  <p id=result2></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wont recommend this method, but still you can use this.
`event.target.nextElementSibling`, this will always grab the next element to the element where the click is triggered. in your case it is all enough

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = 2;
  var y = x + 3;
  event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = y;
}
```

```css
.mobile {
  display: none;
}

.desktop {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="desktop"> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="mobile"> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
  <p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which is much scalable.

Its better to replace the id's with class name (result) and use `querySelectorAll` to get all nodes with that class name. Then loop over the list and set the innerHTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.mobile {display:none;}
.desktop {display:block;}

@media screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .mobile {display:block;}
    .desktop {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="desktop">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p class=result></p>
</div>
<div class="mobile">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p class=result></p>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = 2;
        var y = x + 3;
        document.querySelectorAll(".result").forEach(function(element){ element.innerHTML = y });
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```